How to use GridSearchCV on a customized estimator?
I built a custom Estimator using sklearn BaseEstimator and ClassifierMixin. But when it comes to cross validation, GridSearchCV gives me nan values on the score.
Here is the code of the estimator :
class RegressionClassifier(ClassifierMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, regressor=RidgeCV(cv=10, fit_intercept=True), alpha=0, n_components=1):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.regressor = regressor
        self.estimator = None

    def fit(self, X, y):
        pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
            ('imputate', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="median")),
            ('scale', StandardScaler()),
            ('reduce', PCA(self.n_components)),
            ('regress', self.regressor)
        ])
        self.estimator = pipe.fit(X, y)
        return self
        
    def predict(self, X):
        predictions = self.estimator.predict(X)
        converter = [
        predictions < -self.alpha,
        (-self.alpha <= predictions) & (predictions < self.alpha),
        predictions >= self.alpha
         ]
        classes = [2, 0, 0]
        predicted_class = np.select(converter, classes)
        return predicted_class

    def score(self, X, y):
        y_true = train_new_y[y.index]
        return accuracy_score(y_true, y_true)    


This is supposed to return 1 as score since I compute the accuracy of to identical predictions.
The Estimator works as follow :

Pipeline (which does a linear regression) -> output (regression results vector)

Converter (which take the pipeline results) -> output (classes by some magical operations on regression results)

Score should take generated classes and output accuracy between those classes and a target vector


Results of the gridsearch:
Fitting 5 folds for each of 100 candidates, totalling 500 fits
[CV 1/5] END ........alpha=0.0, n_components=50.0;, score=nan total time=   0.2s
[CV 2/5] END ........alpha=0.0, n_components=50.0;, score=nan total time=   0.1s
[CV 3/5] END ........alpha=0.0, n_components=50.0;, score=nan total time=   0.2s


I resolved the issue doing this :

Create a custom score function (It is important to know that the API should be func(estimator, X, y) where X will be the data matrix passed by gridsearchcv and y the corresponding output)

    def scorer(estimator, X, y):
        predicted_class = estimator.predict(X)
        return accuracy_score(predicted_class, train_new_y[y.index])


Passing this function as a parameter of GridSearchCV

    olm = RegressionClassifier()
    params = {
        "alpha":np.linspace(0,1,10),
        "n_components":np.linspace(50, 200, 10)
    }
    poly_cv = GridSearchCV(olm, params, scoring=scorer, verbose=3)

